# Ubuntu Server DNS/Nameserver setup

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, dns

I have purchased a dedicated server and had Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

I have set everything up that I need, including the firewall and control panel which is server pilot.  I plan on using this server to host multiple WordPress sites.

When I purchase a new domain, I need to be able to change the name server of that domain to point to my dedicated server so the control panel will allow me to install my WordPress sites.  Just like I would do with shared hosting with Hostgator or Bluehost.

What do I need to do to setup the DNS and custom nameservers to be able to do this?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **bind9** or **powerdns** for DNS server. I use bind9 for 50 domains and it works greatly fast. You can follow this [official tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto) from Ubuntu.

Comment: If I register a domain through GoDaddy to use on this server, do I need to setup a caching, master or secondary DNS server though Bind9?

Comment: You need a primary master server. If you also want a fail over dns server, you can buy another server or VPS and create a secondary dns server on it.